# I've just arrived to Skellige in Witcher 3. How deep am I into the game?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm in awe with the game and I play it rarely, bits by bits, so it lasts longer, so I try to count every single chapter.

How deep in am I?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Skellige at about 5% of completion. The game is set up in a way for you to find Ciri by doing a bunch of different quests around all parts of the game world.

Just because you went to Skellige doesn't mean you have completed anything except the tutorial area and unlocking Novigrad.

There is no way to assume how far you are just by being in Skellige.

Comment: Don't forget the reasonable chunk of change to charter the boat.

Answer (score 0):

I often think about the main story line of the game in terms of Chapters.

1. The Investigation: What has Ciri been up to?  In total, this is the better part of the main story line, if you don't count DLCs.  If done in order of recommended level, you'll investigate her Velen Story, then her Novigrad Story, then her Skellige Story, but this order is by no means important.

   > It's not explicitly stated, but Ciri's personal story line seems to run in this order: Skellige Forest -> Velen (Crones -> King of Wolves -> Cocatrice) -> Novigrad -> Skellige Town
2. > Cure Uma.
3. Collect on Debts.  (Side quests can be important.)
4. > Retrieve Ciri from her hide-out & The-Big-Fight Pt. 1.  Prior to starting this, you'll be asked if you *really* want to.  Ask yourself, have you collected on all available Debts?
5. Collect even more powerful Allies.
6. The-Big-Fight Pt. 2

Of course there is *much* more to the game than just the main story line.  Rich side quests & points of interest are really not to be missed.

Answer (score -1):

If I can remember right it's the third our of 3 main zones. So 66%.

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/72421500 Gamespot gives it about 60-65%.

That is only counting the main game. There are 2 DLCs that would be about the size of a zone. So if counting with DLC, about 40%.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like I skipped Novigrad's story. I just had the 1000 gold and went to Skellige.

Comment: @JonathanGuerin: If you skipped Novigrad that only means you'll have to go back to Novigrad. The new area is open for your exploration early on, but the "66%" estimate is for "Finished Novigrad/Vellen" not for "skipped them".

Answer (score -1):

Surely there are other ways to tell, e.g.: how many hours have you played? Divide that by, oh, say, 250.

That is: if you are really enjoying The Witcher, and you continue to enjoy it, it's quite likely you'll spend hundreds of hours playing it.

I believe I spent nearly 200 hours playing it, and I certainly wasn't finished by then.

Comment: Got 100hours on a normal, not that completionist playthough, with DLC.